# What does header_lws status mean in boost http server example?

Tags: http, networking, boost, http-headers, boost-asio

read the boost http server example (see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp11_examples.html) And in the request_parser.cpp file, I see the header_lws status. Part of the codes are below:

```
case header_line_start:
if (input == '\r')
{
    state_ = expecting_newline_3;
    return indeterminate;
}
else if (!req.headers.empty() && (input == ' ' || input == '\t'))
{
    state_ = header_lws;
    return indeterminate;
}
else if (!is_char(input) || is_ctl(input) || is_tspecial(input))
{
    return bad;
}
else
{
    req.headers.push_back(header());
    req.headers.back().name.push_back(input);
    state_ = [header_name];
    return indeterminate;
}
case header_lws:
if (input == '\r')
{
    state_ = expecting_newline_2;
    return indeterminate;
}
else if (input == ' ' || input == '\t')
{
    return indeterminate;
}
else if (is_ctl(input))
{
    return bad;
}
else
{
    state_ = header_value;
    req.headers.back().value.push_back(input);
    return indeterminate;
}
```

What does header_lws status mean in boost http server example?

Answer (score 1):

LWS stands for *linear white space*. You can get more information on HTTP headers' format in the [appropriate RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html).

Comment: Thanks, but I saw that link already, still don't understand it...:-(

Comment: @injoy "linear white space" is a space character or horizontal tab character. Whenever the header parser encounters lws in a non-empty header, it enters `header_lws` state. What's unclear in that?

Comment: Could you give me an example of where the lws would be in a header entry? Thanks.